# Amazon Load Balancers dropping Web Socket connections to TorqueBox

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, jruby, amazon-elb, torquebox

I'm running TorqueBox on Amazon AWS. I've created a load balancer, which does TCP pass through for Web Socket connections on port 8675. When I first load up the page this seems to work quite nicely, however if I leave the page open for a while, the connection just stops working. I don't get an error message, it just silently ignores any further messages sent over the connection. If I reload the page at this point, everything works fine again.

I've tried connecting to individual nodes in the cluster directly, and the connection does not get dropped in that case, so my suspicion is that it has something to do with the load balancers.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

More information about your specific architecture might be useful, but my first guess is that you should enable session stickiness so that requests from the same host get directed to the same machine on AWS (if the request gets directed to another machine the protocol would have to be renegociated).